# What is --no-sandbox argument for atom?

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, atom-editor

**What does the `--no-sandbox` argument mean for `atom`?** ([Atom Text Editor](https://atom.io/))

`atom --help` and `atom -h` make no mention of it.
I do not have a man page for `atom` and I do not see one online.
The [Atom docs and discussion](https://atom.io/docs) seem to have no mention of the argument.

I currently have Atom version 1.58.0

Comment: As far as I know, the `--no-sandbox` flag is not meant for end-users, since it controls the sandbox settings for Sinon, which is used by Atom's tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom appears to inherit `--no-sandbox` from a dependency.
Atom uses Electron which uses Chromium.

The [Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox/#disabling-chromiums-sandbox-testing-only) explain:

> #### Disabling Chromium's sandbox (testing only)
>
> You can also disable Chromium's sandbox entirely with the `--no-sandbox` CLI flag, which will disable the sandbox for all processes (including utility processes). We highly recommend that you only use this flag for testing purposes, and never in production.

Answer (score -1):

Sandbox means recursive pretest before production. So it means that it won't test anything but just runs the mode you choose without testing

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: Actually, sandbox is known as convention before production roadmaps in many integrations. So, IMO atom team should have thought no need to document